# Evenly space in printed text

Tags: java

[printed text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoKiC.png)

that is the code used to print
I want to make a table which have days then hour slots
just will add 9-11 am 11-1 pm and so on..
for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++) {

```
String day = "";
switch (k) {
    case (0):
        day = "Sat";
        break;
    case (1):
        day = "Sun";
        break;
    case (2):
        day = "Mon";
        break;
    case (3):
        day = "Tue";
        break;
    case (4):
        day = "Wed";
        break;
    case (5):
        day = "Thu";
        break;
}
System.out.print(day + " :");
for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < d.size(); i++) {
        char t = d.get(i).getStatus(k, j);
        if (t == 'A') {
            System.out.print(d.get(i).getName() + " :" + d.get(i).getSpecialization() + " ");
        }
    }
    System.out.print("|");
}

System.out.println("");
```

}
}

Comment: Personally, I'd probably use fixed-width fields, as
a. You're not going to get a  table that's got a massive amount of whitespace in it caused by just one excessively long piece of content
b. It's going to be much easier to implement
A long field would be printed: "|This is a very very ver...|"